# Set onClickListener for multiple TextView's in multiple rows of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview, onclicklistener

I have set up a `ListView` from an  `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` called data of data that looks like this

```
data = {{"cat1","cat2","cat3","cat4"},
                      {"dog1","dog2","dog3"},
                      {"lion1"},
                      {"monkey1","monkey2"}};
```

And I have set it up like this:

```
public static final String[] weekdayStringArray = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = data.get(position);
         String dayString = weekdayStringArray[dayNumber];

         switch(stringArrayList.size()){
            case 4:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.four_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView mealOne_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView);
                TextView mealTwo_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondMealTextView);
                TextView mealThree_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thirdMealTextView);
                TextView mealFour_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fourthMealTextView);
                TextView dayText_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
                dayText_Four.setText(dayString);
                mealOne_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealTwo_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(1).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(1).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealThree_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(2).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(2).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealFour_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(3).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(3).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 3:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.three_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView mealOne_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView_Three);
                TextView mealTwo_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondMealTextView_Three);
                TextView mealThree_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thirdMealTextView_Three);
                TextView dayText_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_Three);
                dayText_Three.setText(dayString);
                mealOne_Three.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealTwo_Three.setText(stringArrayList.get(1).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(1).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealThree_Three.setText(stringArrayList.get(2).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(2).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 2:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.two_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView mealOne_Two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView_Two);
                TextView mealTwo_Two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondMealTextView_Two);
                TextView dayText_Two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_Two);
                dayText_Two.setText(dayString);
                mealOne_Two.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealTwo_Two.setText(stringArrayList.get(1).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(1).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 1:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.one_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView mealOne_One = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView_One);
                TextView dayText_One = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_One);
                dayText_One.setText(dayString);
                mealOne_One.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 0:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.zero_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView dayText_Zero = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_Zero);
                dayText_Zero.setText(dayString + "(Closed)");
                break;
         }
return convertView;
```

And now I want to add an `onClickListener` so that I can click a `TextView` in a row. And when this `TextView` is clicked I move to a new `Activity`passing the text of the `TextView` that was clicked and the text of the dayTextView that was in the same row as the `TextView` that was clicked.

Now I don't want to set a bunch of `onClickListners` for each `TextView` so what is an **efficient** way of doing this for all the `TextView`s in the rows of my `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

In the xml for each textView set the onClick to the same method

```
android:onClick= "itemtapped"
```

Then call item tapped in your activity and have it get the textview name and position number so you know which one was tapped.

Option 2:

Make a custom funciton in the activity that takes the item that was tapped

Something like this

```
       public void setOnClickListener(TextView... arrayOfView, int position){

     TextView[] ]textViewArray = textViewArray;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < textViewArray.length ; ++i){

        int index = i; 
        textViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourTargetActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                     int textViewNumber = position;

                }
        });
    }
```

And then pass in the position so you know what one it is and the textview in that row

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look for any child of TextView instance in your convertView. This method uses Breadth First Search algorithm to search for TextView instance.

```
private void setOnClickListenerOnTextViews(View contentViev, OnClickListener listener) {
            ArrayList<View> unvisited = new ArrayList<View>();
            unvisited.add(contentView);
            while (!unvisited.isEmpty()) {
                View child = unvisited.remove(0);
                if(child instanceof TextView) {
                    child.setOnClickListener(listener);
                    continue;
                }
                if (!(child instanceof ViewGroup)){
                    continue;
                }
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) child;
                final int childCount = group.getChildCount();
                for (int i=0; i< childCount; i++){
                    unvisited.add(group.getChildAt(i));
                }
            }
           }
}
```

Call this method in your getView() method:

```
public View getView(.....){
//...
setOnClickListenerOnTextViews(convertView,mClickListener)
return convertView;
}
```

EDIT: For the sake of copy and paste solution, `mClickListener` is listener instance somewhere in your code:

```
private View.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnclickListerner(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v){
   //do your thing here.
 }
};
```

Comment: I get compile error `cannot resolve mClickListener` where and what do I set that as?

Comment: Why people are always going for copy-and-paste solution? mClickListener is interface instance where instantiate somewhere in your code.

Comment: I don't know not sure what you mean, could you explain

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is manually setting click listener for each `TextView`. Why? because you already have found them `(findViewById)` so again traversing the view tree is really bad idea`(Breadth First Search)`. So all you can do is creating a function and then passing your `TextViews` to it. you can do some refactoring to have a clean code though.

```
       public void addClickListenerToTextView(TextView... textViewArray){

        final TextView[] finalTextViewArray = textViewArray;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < finalTextViewArray.length-1 ; ++i){

            final int index = i; 
            textViewArray[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourTargetActivity.class);
                         intent.putExtra("meal" + index ,finalTextViewArray[index].getText().toString());
                         intent.putExtra("dayText" , finalTextViewArray[finalTextViewArray.length-1].getText().toString());
                         startActivity(intent);

                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

then you can call this function like this:

```
 addClickListenerToTextView(mealOne_Three,mealTwo_Three,mealThree_Three,dayText_Three);
```

so before each break call the above function with all the textviews for that row. Note that you must always pass day textview as the last textview.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like a generic `OnClickListener` that holds all the information you need for the new `Activity`:

```
public static final String[] weekdayStringArray = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getWeekdays();

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = getItem(position);
    String dayString = weekdayStringArray[dayNumber];

    MyClickListener myClicker = new MyClickListener(dayString);

    switch (stringArrayList.size()) {
    case 4:
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.four_meal_item_view, parent, false);
        TextView mealOne_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView);
        TextView mealTwo_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondMealTextView);
        TextView mealThree_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thirdMealTextView);
        TextView mealFour_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fourthMealTextView);
        TextView dayText_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
        dayText_Four.setText(dayString);
        mealOne_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        mealTwo_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(1).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(1).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        mealThree_Four
                .setText(stringArrayList.get(2).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(2).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        mealFour_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(3).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(3).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        applyClickListeners(myClicker, mealOne_Four, mealTwo_Four, mealThree_Four, mealFour_Four, dayText_Four);
        break;
    case 3:
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.three_meal_item_view, parent, false);
        TextView mealOne_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView_Three);
        TextView mealTwo_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondMealTextView_Three);
        TextView mealThree_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thirdMealTextView_Three);
        TextView dayText_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_Three);
        dayText_Three.setText(dayString);
        mealOne_Three.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        mealTwo_Three.setText(stringArrayList.get(1).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(1).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        mealThree_Three.setText(stringArrayList.get(2).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + stringArrayList.get(2).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        applyClickListeners(myClicker, mealOne_Three, mealTwo_Three, mealThree_Three, dayText_Three);
        break;
    case 2:
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.two_meal_item_view, parent, false);
        TextView mealOne_Two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView_Two);
        TextView mealTwo_Two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondMealTextView_Two);
        TextView dayText_Two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_Two);
        dayText_Two.setText(dayString);
        mealOne_Two.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        mealTwo_Two.setText(stringArrayList.get(1).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(1).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        applyClickListeners(myClicker, mealOne_Two, mealTwo_Two, dayText_Two);
        break;
    case 1:
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.one_meal_item_view, parent, false);
        TextView mealOne_One = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView_One);
        TextView dayText_One = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_One);
        dayText_One.setText(dayString);
        mealOne_One.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
        applyClickListeners(myClicker, mealOne_One, dayText_One);
        break;
    case 0:
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.zero_meal_item_view, parent, false);
        TextView dayText_Zero = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_Zero);
        dayText_Zero.setText(dayString + "(Closed)");
        applyClickListeners(myClicker, dayText_Zero);
        break;
    }
    return convertView;
}

private void applyClickListeners(MyClickListener clicker, View... toApply) {
    for (View view : toApply) {
        view.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    }
}

class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private String dayText;

    public MyClickListener(String dayText) {
        this.dayText = dayText;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do your thing
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the Listener on your Activity, then pass the activity as the listener to every clickable item. This way you only have to create one listener, it doesn't leak memory and if you have to change the way items are displayed you don't have to change every single listener.

1. Create a SoftReference in the adapter to store the activity safely
2. Pass the activity to every textview as the listener
3. implements View.OnClickListener in the activity
4. Cast the view you're passed back to a TextView
5. Create a new intent
6. Get the text, attach it to the intent
7. Start the new activity