# One onClickListener for multiple TextViews

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I have a ListView that was multiple rows, each with multiple textViews, now it would be inconvenient and bad programming to set an onClickListener for each one.

How could I set an onClickListener for all the TextViews, as each one will perform the same intent (it goes to the same next activity). But each on passes its text as an extra in that intent.

So how could I set this up for the TextViews, with on Click Listineres?

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

Okay Sorry I might not have fully explained this for the ListView that I have set up.

I have 5 different type of cell. One with 4 textViews, one with 3 textViews, and so on going down to 0.

In my getView I have it set up like this

```
switch(stringArrayList.size()){
            case 4:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.four_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView mealOne_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView);
                TextView mealTwo_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondMealTextView);
                TextView mealThree_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thirdMealTextView);
                TextView mealFour_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fourthMealTextView);
                TextView dayText_Four = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView);
                dayText_Four.setText(dayString);
                mealOne_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealTwo_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(1).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(1).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealThree_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(2).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(2).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealFour_Four.setText(stringArrayList.get(3).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(3).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 3:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.three_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView mealOne_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView_Three);
                TextView mealTwo_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondMealTextView_Three);
                TextView mealThree_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thirdMealTextView_Three);
                TextView dayText_Three = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_Three);
                dayText_Three.setText(dayString);
                mealOne_Three.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealTwo_Three.setText(stringArrayList.get(1).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(1).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealThree_Three.setText(stringArrayList.get(2).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(2).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 2:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.two_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView mealOne_Two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView_Two);
                TextView mealTwo_Two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondMealTextView_Two);
                TextView dayText_Two = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_Two);
                dayText_Two.setText(dayString);
                mealOne_Two.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                mealTwo_Two.setText(stringArrayList.get(1).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(1).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 1:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.one_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView mealOne_One = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstMealTextView_One);
                TextView dayText_One = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_One);
                dayText_One.setText(dayString);
                mealOne_One.setText(stringArrayList.get(0).substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + stringArrayList.get(0).substring(1).toLowerCase());
                break;
            case 0:
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.zero_meal_item_view, parent, false);
                TextView dayText_Zero = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayTextView_Zero);
                dayText_Zero.setText(dayString + "(Closed)");
                break;
```

And no for the click on the textView I want to go to a new activity and pass the text of the TextView that was clicked and the text of the dayTextView of that row.

I hope this explains it better.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413468/set-onclicklistener-for-multiple-textviews-in-multiple-rows-listview/27473609#27473609

Answer (score 0):

you should add `onClickListener` to each `TextView` in your `Adapter`'s `getView` method.

EDIT :

set `onClickListener` for every `TextView` in your list. then in `onClick` method :

```
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
     Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
     i.putExtra("text", ((TextView) view).getText.toString());
     context.startActivity(this);
 }
```

Comment: your view holder for list items. and if you are not using any view holders, replace it with convertView or whatever is your view.

Comment: okay any chance you could see the edit, I explain my problem better

Answer (score 0):

You can create **OnClickListener** for every TextView in adapter when creating a view in **getView** method.

There is also second option. Use one global **OnClickListener** and....

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   if(view instanceof YourFunkyCustomTextViewWithData)
   {
       ((YourFunkyCustomTextViewWithData) view).getFunkyData()
        ... and do what you want with that
   }
}
```